# Thingsboard Gauge Widget Max Value

Tags: thingsboard

I am new to TB and I wanted to know if I can set the max value on a gauge dynamically from a(n) device/entity attribute.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Having the same question. The device sends it minimum and maximum range once when it is registered in the network. That changes between devices. Thingsboard widget should use that min max range attribute from the device to change its min and max accordingly.

Comment: Did you ever manage to find a solution for this?